# Why does the eMail in my Rules Component use a theme that differs from page-theme?

Tags: theming, rules, emails

I use the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module to send follow-up emails, which works fine.

In the past I used a different theme for my site, and somehow this theme (call it "old-theme" for now) is applied when a follow-up email is sent ([Mime Mail](https://www.drupal.org/project/mimemail)).

How do I apply the current site-theme to my Rules Component?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check the result you get if you do NOT tell [Mime Mail](https://www.drupal.org/project/mimemail) to use the site's stylesheet. And combine this with creating a file in your theme that is named `mail.css`. If you do that, then [Mime Mail](https://www.drupal.org/project/mimemail) should automatically use that when sending emails. For more details on that, refer to its [README.txt](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/mimemail/tree/README.txt#n79), i.e.:

> Email messages are formatted using the `mimemail-message.tpl.php` template.
>   This includes a CSS style sheet and uses an HTML version of the text.
>   The included CSS is either:
>
> - the `mail.css` file found anywhere in your theme folder or
> - the combined CSS style sheets of your theme if enabled.

Also make sure your theme is set as "Theme to render the emails" within `admin/config/system/mailsystem`. Without that, the stylesheets used by emails sent via cron (for example) may not look like you want them to look.